# How can I click on the link here with using id.class.href python selenium, I using pyCharm

Tags: python, class, selenium-webdriver, href

How can I click on the link here with using id.class.href python selenium, I using pyCharm  *href is Changeable

i try 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='result_26']//a[@class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal']/@href").click()`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABIs4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clicking the href *attribute* instead of the `<a>` *tag*.

Assuming your xpath is correct, just remove the `/@href` from the end and it should ideally work.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='result_26']//*[contains(@class,'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal')]").click()
i try * and a dosnt work

Comment: I did
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@id='result_26']")
element2.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@class='a-link-normal s-access-detail-page  s-color-twister-title-link a-text-normal']").click()